# No Frills magento layout

Tags: magento, magento-layout-xml

I am going through examples on "No frills magento layout" and on example 1.11 "A full page layout" is not working for me
i am getting blank page

looks like  there is a problem with fetchview

```
public function fetchView ( $fileName )
{
// ignores file name , just uses a simple include with template name
$this -> setScriptPath (
Mage :: getModuleDir ('', ' Nofrills_Booklayout ') .
DS .
'design '
);
return parent :: fetchView ($this -> getTemplate ());
}
```

i am using magento 1.7.0.2 community edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution myself. Actually the following method was missing in the template file

```
public function setScriptPath($dir)
{
    parent::setScriptPath($dir);    //if anything important happens up there in a future version
    $this->_viewDir = Mage::getModuleDir('', 'Nofrills_Booklayout') . DS . 'design';
    return $this;                   //as the original 
}
```

After adding this full page layout is build up.